# Akka's message delivery guarantees

Tags: akka

I am trying to insert 20k records into MySQL database using AKKA. I have found 19,994 records have been inserted and rest 6 records were not inserted. I have read that AKKA does not guarantee message delivery. Is there any way to deal with this problem ?

Comment: That's a pretty small number of messages. I'd be surprised if those 6 missing records had to do with 'missed' messages. You should look at your code and see if you are swallowing an error somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Akka's message send semantics are exactly **at-most-once-delivery**.

If you need re-delivery please check out the new **at-least-once-delivery** trait added to akka-persistence: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#At-Least-Once_Delivery

However your question does not really include your setup - something else could have gone wrong - persistence failures etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [At-Least-Once Delivery](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#At-Least-Once_Delivery).

But pay attention to the notes in the documentation :

- this is not ***at-most-once delivery*** that means you have to handle duplicate messages.
- the order might not be preserved.

Hope this helps.